# Chip identification in nonin module

Tags: hardware, pcb

This chip is off the Nonin OEM MODULE III.

I would appreciate if anyone can find out what this chip and datasheet is.

I have tried looking up the numbers in alldatasheet.com and the company to no avail.

It has markings of 5359-045E , 5361-005E , © 2007 NM (I)?

[image: chip]

Thank you

Comment: those are probably firmware version  numbers... why do you need to identify the chip?

Answer (score 2):

Often vendors will make life hard for folks like us by putting a sticker on top of an IC.  Peel it off and if necessary remove the icky bits with an alcoholic wipe and you should have a much better idea of what the chip actually is.